ESLint - Plugin for concentric pattern with styled components
Does anyone know of a plugin for implementing a concentric system into styled components? I'm looking for an easy way to implement something like this with ESLint
I searched google and stack overflow but didn't find anything

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
